# How to Obfuscate NDK library?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, obfuscation

I have a C++ NDK library that I want to obfuscate. I have tried using https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki but I am unable to configure it for the latest NDK version. Are there any other free compile time obfuscating or post processing tools/scripts I can incorporate to obfuscate my library?

Comment: There's isn't much available for NDK obfuscation, at least to my knowledge. However, if your NDK library isn't too big (consists of method counts < 10/20) then consider obfuscating it manually, a tad boring task but makes the reverse engineering a bit tougher.

Comment: Sigh.. Thanks, will give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://xz.aliyun.com/t/6643) article , there is another option named [Hikari](https://github.com/HikariObfuscator/Hikari) for NDK obfuscation .But I didn't test it myself .Here is an [article](https://www.jianshu.com/p/baa5be56530f) to read more .You have to translate it .It's not English.